# Which ARM based development boards should I use?

Tags: android, arm, trustzone

I want to start a project in which I want to do authenticated boot for Android based on [ARM's TrustZone technology](http://www.arm.com/products/processors/technologies/trustzone.php).

Which board should I use?

The minimal requirements:

- ARM V7 instruction set
- USB, VGA/HDMI connectors
- touch-screen connectors
- Flash capabilities
- 512 MB RAM
- TrustZone enabled
- JTAG connector and DB-9 UART port
- power supply
- Board should have documentation available
- Android drivers and codecs as I will run Android on it.

So far, I found the Freescale i.MX53, the Pandaboard, the Beagle board xM (which has TrustZone disabled, apparently), the Atmel-based boards, the Versiatile Express A9x4 and the RealView Platform Baseboard for ARM1176JZF-S. But it is often unclear whether the TrustZone extensions are enabled or not.

Comment: Feel free to comment, as this is my first question on stackoverflow.

Comment: Don't got much for you, sorry.

Comment: Hmm, does the nook color have TrustZone?

Comment: Thank you for your comments and editing so far @MichaelDorgan & dwelch & Charles. For as far as I can see: the Nook color does have trustZone, but you cannot get access to that just like that. I think I have to go for the Freescale i.MX53 as it is the only affordable dev board that has TrustZone Enabled (both as a processor feature and all the extended memory stuff that I need to let it work). So how does this work: I should not just answer my own question right?

Comment: If you have a good answer, then answer it.  That way others will have it in the knowledge base here, and you get a badge for it too :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After doing a broad search, it seems that the [Freescale iMX53](http://www.freescale.com/webapp/sps/site/prod_summary.jsp?code=IMX53QSB&tid=vanIMXQUICKSTART) is probably the board to go, as it is not too expensive, has full Trustzone support (not only the processor, but also the memory/board is TrustZone aware) and it seems usable.

Answer (score 1):

I have been recently working on

1. TI Sitara AM335x
2. Atmel at91sama5d31-ek

Both them appear to be good, but the TI sitara appear to have better documentation and a larger community (Sep 2013)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the freescale i.MX53. Many trustzone projects are on it

Comment: Could you elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: @abarisone The i.MX53 QSB as said before has full trustzone support. Their is many project about trustzone who where made on it ( Genode, AndixOS...) I didn't use it yet but i will start development on it in two weeks.